# jUnit тестирование простейшего метода void

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Имеется простейший метод

```
public final void changeChanel(final int newChanel) {
    this.chanelSet = newChanel;
}
```

В специфику программы, на этот метод необходимо написать unit-тест.Возможно ли написать тест на этот метод такого вида? Затрудняюсь реализовать.

Comment: Да, проверять что значение правда устанавливается и устанавливается корректно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно простейшие методы типа геттеров/сеттеров не тестируются: даже если вы там и налажаете, ошибка поймается другими тестами.

Если очень хочется, то вам нужно после смены канала вызвать некоторый метод, который вернет значение канала (геттер) и проверить его значение. Однако может статься, что контрактом такой метод не предусмотрен. Добавлять же его только для использования в тестах -- дурной тон.